# Refactor Gatsby Image Query

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am currently using Gatsby and gatsby-image within my IndexPage component. I am looking to refactor the code below into a single React component, as there is unnecessary duplication:

```
          ...
          return (
          <div>
            <h1>Startups</h1>
            <p>Copy</p>
            <Img fluid={props.data.imageOne.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h1>People</h1>
            <p>Copy</p>
            <Img fluid={props.data.imageTwo.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h1>Data</h1>
            <p>Copy</p>
            <Img fluid={props.data.imageThree.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        )

export const fluidImage = graphql`
fragment fluidImage on File {
  childImageSharp {
    fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
    }
  }
}
`

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    imageOne: file(relativePath: { eq: "igemA.png" }) {
      ...fluidImage
    }
    imageTwo: file(relativePath: { eq: "inephemeraA.png" }) {
      ...fluidImage
    }
    imageThree: file(relativePath: { eq: "polypA.png" }) {
      ...fluidImage
    }
  }
```

That resembles something like this:

```
const NewComponent = (props) => (
          <div>
            <h1>props.heading</h1>
            <p>props.body</p>
            <Img fluid={props.data.[props.image].childImageSharp.fluid}/>
          </div>

)
```

How can I change the graphql query so that I can render an image depending on the props passed to the NewComponent?

Comment: The same way you're modifying the query now? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have misunderstood, I don't think you need to change your query to accomplish that. Just pass the result of each query to your child component as a prop.

```
// components/newComponent.js

import React from "react"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const NewComponent = ({ image, heading, body }) => (
  <>
    <h1>{ heading }</h1>
    <p>{ body }</p>
    <Img fluid={ image.childImageSharp.fluid } />
  </>
)

export default NewComponent
```

---

```
// index.js

import React from "react"
import {graphql} from "gatsby"

import NewComponent from "../components/newComponent"

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {
  const { imageOne, imageTwo } = data
  return (
  <>
    <NewComponent image={ imageOne } heading="heading 1" body="body 1" />
    <NewComponent image={ imageTwo } heading="heading 1" body="body 2" />
  </>
)}

export default IndexPage

export const fluidImage = graphql`
fragment fluidImage on File {
  childImageSharp {
    fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
    }
  }
}
`

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    imageOne: file(relativePath: { eq: "gatsby-astronaut.png" }) {
      ...fluidImage
    }
    imageTwo: file(relativePath: { eq: "gatsby-icon.png" }) {
      ...fluidImage
    }
  }
`
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-8f6cl) to test the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables to the GraphQL query like this:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query image($src: String!) file(relativePath: { eq: $src }) {
      ...fluidImage
    }`
```

and this is an example how to [Pass Variable](https://github.com/m-allanson/page-query-demo)